# Specify Tab or TabID for chrome.tabCaptureAPI?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

**Short Version of Question:** Is it possible to, given a tab ID, select which version I want tabCapture to record?

**Slightly Longer Version:** I am developing an extension for myself that has a manifest like this:

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "tabCapture",
    "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "./popup.html",
        "default_icon": "./icon.png"
    }
  }
```

My background.js code:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

console.log("Background started")

async function screenRecord(tab) {
    console.log("Started recording")

    /* Where do i put selected tab? */
    chrome.tabCapture.capture({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    }, 
    (stream) => {
        /* Goes somewhere later*/
    })

    await sleep(5000);

    /* stop recording of that with the ID */


}

async function startRun() {
    let myTabs = []
    for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url:"https://www.google.com/"}, (e) => {
            myTabs[i] = e;
        });
        await sleep(5000);
        chrome.tabs.update( myTabs[i]['id'], { url: "http://stackoverflow.com//" } ); 
        await sleep(5000);
        
        /* Pass the tab id to be capture d*/
        screenRecord(myTabs[i]['id'])

        await sleep(5000);
        chrome.tabs.remove(myTabs[i]['id']);
        await sleep(10000);
        
    }
}

startRun()
```

The idea is that, given a tabID, i can tell tabCapture to record a specific tab and then stop it after 5 seconds (in this scenario).

How would I be able to do that since tabCapture does not provide a method to specify an ID?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find an answer for this? Ta.